# Auto-click button element on page load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button, modal-dialog, pageload

If I wanted to auto-click a button element on page load, how would I go about this using jQuery?

The button html is

```
<button class="md-trigger" id="modal" data-modal="modal"></button>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You would simply use jQuery like so...

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#modal').click();
});
</script>
```

Use the click function to auto-click the #modal button

Comment: Will this trigger an `ng-click` on that button as well?

Comment: click() is deprecated now. Use " trigger("click") " instead. 

<script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#modal').trigger('click');
});
</script>

Comment: How to make it trigger only once? .this one loads it every time when page is ready

Answer (score 33):

JavaScript Pure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("modal").click();
</script>
```

---

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modal").trigger('click'); 
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modal").click(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the following code

```
$("#modal").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried the following ways in first jQuery, then JavaScript:

**jQuery**:

```
 window.location.href = $(".contact").attr('href');
 $('.contactformone').trigger('click');
```

This is the best way in **JavaScript**:

```
 document.getElementById("id").click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use that and adjust the time you want to launch 1= onload 2000= 2 sec

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#click').click(function(){
        alert('button clicked');
    });
  // set time out 2 sec
     setTimeout(function(){
        $('#click').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.container{
padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="col text-center">
<button id="click" class="btn btn-danger">Jquery Auto Click</button>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We should rather use Javascript.

```
    <button href="images/car.jpg" id="myButton">
        Here is the Button to be clicked
    </button>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            document.getElementById("myButton").click();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: repetition of answers..!!