# How to auto click button in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the below button on my page. I want below button to be auto clicked when this page gets loaded. I've tried following various suggestions on the net but I'm unable to find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
 <a data-bind="click: $root.addtocart" class="w-button btn-large" 
    style="text-decoration: none!important;" id="redeemButton">
                        Redeem Now                                                                               
 </a>
```

Comment: you can call the `addtocart()` method on page load

Comment: hi you can do something like this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646881/auto-click-button-element-on-page-load-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-click button element on page load using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646881/auto-click-button-element-on-page-load-using-jquery)

Comment: @VishalPatel there is no mention here of the presence of jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Do it directly in the creation of your viewmodel:

```
function MyViewModel(){
    this.addtocart = function(){
      //Some code
    }
    this.addtocart(); // <-- here
}
```

Comment: If i add  " this.addtocart();" it is auto clicking but the data that is printing is different from the data printed when i manually click on button.

Comment: @pradeep well we don't have the details of what your code does

Comment: When you bind `click: $root.addToCart`, it sends the clicked item as a first argument. (i.e.: `addToCart($data, event)`) Like @GôTô said, you haven't shown us `addToCart`, but I can image it needs to be sent a parameter in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a ready function in your javascript like this..

```js
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        window.getElementById("redeemButton").click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's not really the Knockout way (although it should work). When using a binding framework, jQuery should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: If i paste the above code in my hbs file control is going into function but click is not happening.