# How to refresh the page every 5 seconds and click a button?

Tags: javascript

This only refreshes the page once, I have tested it. How do I make it reload the page every 5 seconds and look for an element then click on it?

```
function reload() {
  document.location.reload();
}

setTimeout(reload, 5000);
```

Comment: [how-to-reload-page-every-5-seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787679/how-to-reload-page-every-5-seconds) & [auto-click-button-element-on-page-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646881/auto-click-button-element-on-page-load-using-jquery)

Comment: Whats your aim ? Do  you want the  page to keep reloading forever ?

Comment: Yes, until the element is found setTimeout refreshes it once

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const button = document.querySelector('.button');
  button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
  window.location.reload();
}, 5000)
```